# Invoke calls Inner Invoke twice

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I were wondered to look into mechanism of event invocation, so as usual I went to whatwg specification.

For performing callback function of event's listener, spec does the following:

1. [dispatch](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch)
2. [invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-invoke)
3. [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke)

It would be simple to understand how dispatching mechanism works if [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) was called by once. But there is case that I can't understand and this case calls [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) twice. What is that case?

**Part of whatwg spec [invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-invoke) algorithm:**

> 8. Let found be the result of running [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) with event, listeners, phase, invocationTargetInShadowTree, and
>    legacyOutputDidListenersThrowFlag if given.
> 9. If found is false and event’s isTrusted attribute is true, then:
>
>    3. [Inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) with event, listeners, phase, invocationTargetInShadowTree, and legacyOutputDidListenersThrowFlag if
>       given.

What is the sense of invocation [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) twice? I remind, [inner invoke](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke) calls function callback of event's listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I remind, inner invoke calls function callback of event's listener

Only if it returns `true` (`found` is `true` within `inner invoke`), but Step 9 clearly only runs when the first call returned `false`, meaning that Step 2 of `inner invoke` didn't iterate even once (no listener matched "For each listener in listeners, whose removed is false"):

> 1. Let *found* be false.
> 2. For each listener in listeners, whose removed is false:
>
>    1. If event’s type attribute value is not listener’s type, then continue.
>    2. **Set *found* to true.**
>
> ...
>
> 3. Return *found*.

*(My emphasis)*

Separately, in your quotes you've left out an important part of `invoke`, which is that it changes the `type` (Step 2) before the second call to `inner invoke`. Which makes the sequence make a lot more sense: First it does an `inner invoke` with the original type (for instance, `animationend`), then if no listeners were found, it tries again with an adjusted type (for instance, `webkitAnimationEnd`).

Comment: Well, you're definitely right. To be honest I was seeing on step 2 and didn't pay attention to it. Now when you have chewed it to me. I got it. Thanks!